# faster way to upload data from Mysql Rstudio

Tags: r

I'm Trying to extract datas from mysql. its about 15.000.000 rows. I dont know how I can get it every times that i try the conection with my sql lost

'''
queryStatus <- paste0("

select ID_SJT_USRO,ID_USRO,DATE(DT_INI_VGNA) as data_status,SJT.ID_STTS_USRO,DS_STTS_USRO from  DWU.TB_SJT_USUARIO AS SJT
LEFT JOIN DWU.TB_ATR_STATUS_USUARIO AS STATUS_USER
ON SJT.ID_STTS_USRO = STATUS_USER.ID_STTS_USRO
WHERE ID_USRO IN (",Id_user_aviso,")
;")

user_status <- dbGetQuery(conn = conStatus("DWU"), queryStatus)'''

Comment: Please share the error log.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.